# VS Code: multi line keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiline, editing

I use a shortcut with `keybindings.json` to put a single line into quotes, ending with a comma.
`text` --> `"text",` this works well, but only for one line.

Now I have a long list of text and would like to put every line into quotes
like this

`text1` --> `"text1",`

`text2` --> `"text2",`

`text3` --> `"text3",`

`text4` --> `"text4",`

Is there a way to do it? Help highly appreicated, because I would gain a lot of time, if i dont have to do it line by line.

Best endo

**edit**:
here is the snippet from `keybindings.json` which puts every line in brackets

```
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+,",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\", "
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use multi line selection with CTRL + ALT + Up/Down arrow and then, after you selected the rows, apply that shortcut of your